Disabling installation of some apps (both through APKs and through app stores) on a stock ROM
I want to disable the installation of some common non-free (proprietary) apps such as Facebook, WhatsApp, and all non-free Google apps, in order to comply with the policies of the FSF to make the ROM free software. The ROM has only FOSS apps installed (microG, Fossify, Revanced, AuroraStore, etc).
I want to do it preferably by modifying the package installer, so that someone can install the ROM by flashing the system.img of it. To accept the risks and use the app anyway, the user will need to install a patched version (APK) of the app modified for privacy, performance, and battery life, which has a different signature (but often the same package name).
The ROM is actually an Android 9 stock ROM (no, it's not a custom ROM), which I debloated and installed FOSS apps.
Is there any way to do this?

Modifying package installer means compiling your own AOSP version. But that is a lot of work. And with bootloader unlocked anybody could still install an APK as system app. Unfortunately you have not explained why you want to do this. If the phone would be just for you, the simple answer would be just don't install these apps. A simple alternative would be creating dummy apps without icon in launcher that use the package names you want to block. BTW: usually a "stock ROM" is an unmodified ROM.

@Robert I clearly mentioned that I wanted to do this to comply with the policies of the FSF to make the ROM a Free operating system. The ROM is not for my use; I created a thread on XDA and released this debloated stock ROM. "Stock ROM" obviously refers to the ROM which came with the device and was loaded onto the device by the OEM. Also, this ROM can still boot with a locked bootloader. But the idea of installing dummy apps is great. I could install these as system apps, and when the user will try to install their apps, it would fail due to signature verification. Thanks for this idea!
